# Can't add Uniswap V2 Periphery as a package to Brownie

Tags: solidity, brownie

I am following Brownie's documentation to add packages to my Solidity project. I have to add `Uniswap/v2-core` and `Uniswap/v2-periphery`. In order to do this I called the following lines in the terminal:

*This one is working correctly, it installed the package*

```
brownie pm install Uniswap/v2-core@1.0.1
```

However when I call the below line I am getting the error `ValueError: Invalid version for this package. Available versions are: 1.0.0-beta.0` what is weird because [on Github](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery) there is the `@1.1.0-beta.0` version instead of `1.0.0-beta.0`

```
brownie pm install Uniswap/v2-periphery@1.1.0-beta.0
```

The question is can I somehow force Brownie to recognize the valid version or is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version of this was also asked on [Stack Exchange ETH](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113319/eth-brownie-how-can-i-import-from-github-when-the-version-number-includes-letter)

> You do exactly as you have here, you add the whole release string.
>
> For example:
>
> ```yaml
> dependencies:
>    - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.2.1-solc-0.7
> compiler:
>     solc:
>         remappings:
>             - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.2.1-> solc-0.7"
> ```
>
> The reason that yours isn't working right now is that https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery doesn't have any releases, it only has tags.
>
> What you could do then, is fork the repo, make a release yourself and point to your own release until they actually release something.

The reason this is failing is that [there are no releases of that package on Github](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-periphery/releases) (as of right now).

Here is what I'd do:

1. Fork the repo
2. Cut a release on your own github
3. Point to that repo in your `brownie-config.yaml` similar to what we show in the quote above.

Comment: Understand it now, this is great. I will use this solution for bigger projects. As now I have to import Uniswap only, I ended up adding the required snippets to the contract manually so I don't have to do this magic.